# "Largest possible object" on size_t explanations

Tags: c++

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304256/what-is-size-of-the-largest-possible-object-on-the-target-platform-in-terms-of) but it's not clear to me. I've just begun learning C++ and stumbled upon size_t. I've read about it and I think I understand its purpose, but on most explanations, they use the phrase "Largest possible object" your system can handle.

What do they mean when they say object? The objects I know are the ones instantiated from classes, but I can add a lot of properties on that object so I don't think this is the type of object that they are referring to.

Comment: Definition of _"Object"_ (it's a C++ Standard's term and is not meant in the Object Orientated sense.  It is a regon of storage that has certain properties): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard meaning of the term *object* is not tied to classes specifically. The term originates from C language and its meaning hasn't changed much in C++. The term "object" is a loose synonym of the term "variable", any variable. Every variable you declare is an object. All of the following are objects

```
int a;                // an object of type 'int'
double b;             // an object of type 'double'
char s[1024];         // an object of type 'char [1024]'
SomeClass x;          // an object of type 'SomeClass'
SomeOtherClass y[10]; // an object of type 'SomeOtherClass [10]'
```

In other words, *objects* are pieces of *data* stored in memory, as opposed to *functions*, which are made of *code*.

The specification of type `size_t` says that it should be able to store the size of the largest object supported by the implementation. Typically, the easiest way to create a large object is to declare an array of large size. Of course, you can also create a large object by creating a sufficiently large class type.

Maximum object size supported by an implementation is typically an inherent property of that implementation (which possibly depends on compiler settings too). It is hardcoded into the implementation. So, if `size_t` is large enough to cover that range, it will always be enough to store the size of any object.

For example, some implementation might limit the maximum object size by 64K bytes. In such implementation `size_t` can be safely defined as a 16-bit unsigned integer. This `size_t` will always be large enough to store the size of any object (the result of any `sizeof`), since the implementation will never allow you to create a larger object or declare a type of larger size.

---

There's another standard type somewhat tied to the largest possible object size - `ptrdiff_t`. This is a *signed* type that is intended to store the difference between two pointers pointing into the same array. If some implementation would allow you to create objects (e.g. a char array) as large as the maximum value of `size_t`, then in order to accommodate any difference between such pointers, `ptrdiff_t` would have to be at least 1 bit wider than `size_t` (due to its signedness). I.e. if `size_t` was 16 bit wide, `ptrdiff_t` would have to be at least 17 bit wide. This is a rather odd situation.

However, fortunately (or unfortunately) implementations are not *required* to be able to store any difference between two pointers in `ptrdiff_t`. Which means that they have an excuse to define `ptrdiff_t` of the same width as `size_t`.

Some implementations take advantage of that excuse: they define `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` of the same width. They allow you to create objects as large as the max value of `size_t`. And also tell you to be careful when subtracting distant pointers: the result might not fit into `ptrdiff_t`, overflow and cause undefined behavior.

Other implementations follow a different approach: they also define `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` of the same width, but they artificially limit the max object size by *half* the range of `size_t`. In such implementations any two pointers that point into the same array can always be safely subtracted. (But obviously you pay for that with max object size reduced by the factor of 2).

Comment: OK that is confusing for me, I thought size_t is defined in header files so I thought that the size is predetermined. But you mentioned any class, so how does the compiler know what the size should be since I can create a class with many members? Or maybe I'm not getting something.

Comment: @g_b: The limitation on the maximum object size is built into your implementation, into your compiler. It is *hardcoded* into your compiler. So, the compiler knows what the maximum size is. And `size_t` is defined in the header file accordingly. Your compiler will not allow you to create an object that is larger than that hardcoded limit. That's how the compiler "knows" what the size should be.

Comment: >artificially limit the max object size by half the range of ```size_t```

Will the compiler throw an error if, using your example above, you create an object that is 64K bytes large?

Answer (score 3):

It's a type that can hold the size (in chars) of the largest chunk of contiguous memory you can possibly allocate. As you observe, objects are made up  of pointers and so on, so the actual amount of memory owned by an object could possibly be greater than `size_t` could represent. However, the size of an object returned by the `sizeof` operator (which doesn't take into account things like dynamic memory allocations to pointers in an object) must be storable in a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
 char array[100000];
```

must have a size which fits in a size_t. The compiler will usually reject for other reasons as arrays approach SIZE_MAX, but SIZE_MAX is a solid limit.

You'll also note that sizeof(int) returns a size_t. However this number is probably 2 or 4 and most unlikely to be greater than 8. So whilst size_t is designed to allow large numbers to be handled, most uses are for small numbers.

You'll also note that the code

```
     int *array = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        array[i] = 0;
```

should really have size_t's for N and i. This is where the size_t idea starts being a nuisance. Unsigned values for array indices make the indices hard to
manipulate.

And "object" in C is anything that can be identified, and occupies contiguous
bytes in memory. So a structure, or an array, or a single variable, or an array of structures. But not a structure plus an array of ints declared after it which just happens to occupy the next memory